# problem with moving files using os.rename

Tags: python, file, operating-system, rename

i have this block of code where i try to move all the files in a folder to a different folder.

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def run():

    print("Do you want to convert 1 file (0) or do you want to convert all the files in a folder(1)")
    oneortwo = input("")

    if oneortwo == "0":
        filepathonefile = input("what is the filepath of your file?")
        filepathonefilewithoutfullpath = os.path.basename(filepathonefile)
        newfolder = "C:/Users/EL127032/Documents/fileconvertion/files/" + filepathonefilewithoutfullpath
        os.rename(filepathonefile,newfolder)
    if oneortwo == "1" :
        filepathdirectory = input("what is the filepath of your folder?")
        filesindirectory = [f for f in listdir(filepathdirectory) if isfile(join(filepathdirectory, f))]
        numberoffiles = len(filesindirectory)
        handlingfilenumber = 0
        while numberoffiles > handlingfilenumber:
            currenthandlingfile = filesindirectory[handlingfilenumber]
            oldpathcurrenthandling = filepathdirectory + "/" + currenthandlingfile
            futurepathcurrenhandlingfile = "C:/Users/EL127032/Documents/fileconvertion/files/" + currenthandlingfile
            os.rename(oldpathcurrenthandling, futurepathcurrenhandlingfile)
```

but when i run this it gives
os.rename(oldpathcurrenthandling, futurepathcurrenhandlingfile)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] System couldn't find the file: 'C:\Users\EL127032\Documents\Eligant - kopie\Klas 1\Stermodules\Basisbiologie/lopen (1).odt' -> 'C:/Users/EL127032/Documents/fileconvertion/files/lopen (1).odt'

can someone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to move the same file twice.

The bug is in this part :

```py
        numberoffiles = len(filesindirectory)
        handlingfilenumber = 0
        while numberoffiles > handlingfilenumber:
            currenthandlingfile = filesindirectory[handlingfilenumber]
            oldpathcurrenthandling = filepathdirectory + "/" + currenthandlingfile
            futurepathcurrenhandlingfile = "C:/Users/EL127032/Documents/fileconvertion/files/" + currenthandlingfile
            os.rename(oldpathcurrenthandling, futurepathcurrenhandlingfile)
```

The first time you loop, `handlingfilenumber` will be 0, so you will move the 0-th file from your `filesindirectory` list.
Then you loop again, `handlingfilenumber` is still 0, so you try to move it again, but it is not there anymore (you moved it already on the first turn).

You forgot to **increment** `handlingfilenumber`. Add `handlingfilenumber += 1` on a line after `os.rename` and you will be fine.

`while` loops are more error-prone than simpler `for` loops, I recommend you use `for` loops when appropriate.
Here, you want to move each file, so a `for` loops suffices :

```py
for filename in filesindirectory:
    oldpathcurrenthandling = filepathdirectory + "/" + currenthandlingfile
    futurepathcurrenhandlingfile = "C:/Users/EL127032/Documents/fileconvertion/files/" + currenthandlingfile
    os.rename(oldpathcurrenthandling, futurepathcurrenhandlingfile)
```

No need to use `len`, initialize a counter, increment it, get the n-th element, ... And fewer lines.

Three other things :

- you could have found the cause of the problem yourself, using **debugging**, there are plenty of ressources online to explain how to do it. Just printing the name of the file about to be copied (`oldpathcurrenthandling`) you would have seen it twice and noticed the problem causing the `os` error.
- your variable names are not very readable. Consider following [the standard style guide about variable names (PEP 8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) and standard jargon, for example `filepathonefilewithoutfullpath` becomes `filename`, `oldpathcurrenthandling` becomes `source_file_path` (following the source/destination convention), ...
- When you have an error, include the stacktrace that Python gives you. It would have pointed directly to the second `os.rename` case, the first one (when you copy only one file) does not contribute to the problem. It also helps finding a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).